# Achartengine thicker bars

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I am working with Achartengine. I am using a barchart to display some data and it displays okay. There is just one thing that I can't do and that is to make the values of the bars not go over other values.

[image]

As you can see from the image, the values overlap each other. Either I need to make the bars thicker or I need to turn the values 45 degrees.

The setBarSpacing does not change anything.
Here is how I create my bar chart:

```
public BarGraph(double[] thisWeekDoubleArray,double[] lastWeekDoubleArray,double yAxisMax, String yTitle,String chartTitle)
{
    
    setData(thisWeekDoubleArray,lastWeekDoubleArray);
    
    mDataset.addSeries(lastWeek.toXYSeries());
    mDataset.addSeries(thisWeek.toXYSeries());
    
    
    // Customize data set 1
    rendererThisWeek.setColor(Color.RED);
    rendererThisWeek.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    rendererThisWeek.setFillPoints(true);
    
    rendererThisWeek.setDisplayChartValues(true); 
    rendererThisWeek.setChartValuesTextSize(16);
    rendererThisWeek.setLineWidth(2);
    rendererThisWeek.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    //rendererThisWeek.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(4);
    
    // Customize data set 2
    rendererLastWeek.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    rendererLastWeek.setPointStyle(PointStyle.TRIANGLE);
    rendererLastWeek.setFillPoints(true);
    
    rendererLastWeek.setDisplayChartValues(true); 
    rendererLastWeek.setChartValuesTextSize(16);
    rendererLastWeek.setLineWidth(2);
    rendererLastWeek.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    //rendererLastWeek.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(4);
    //rendererLastWeek.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER); // Default is center
    
    // Add single renderer to multiple renderer and set some
    // properties for the multiple renderer
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererThisWeek);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererLastWeek);
    
    mRenderer.setChartTitle(chartTitle);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Day #");
    mRenderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
    mRenderer.setBarWidth(30);
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    
    //mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    //mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    
    //For applying background
    //mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    //mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    //mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.BLACK);
    
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(28);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(18);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(18);
    
    // margins - an array containing the margin size values, in this order: top, left, bottom, right
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 35, 20 });
    
    // Sets the legend text size.
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setLegendHeight(45);
    //mRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
    
    // This sets how many x labels should be visible.
    // Since I make my own labels I have to set this to 0
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    // Adds the labels for the x axis.
    // This is the days.
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "-6");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "-5");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "-4");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "-3");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "-2");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "-1");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, "0");
    
    mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(0.8f);
    
    // Aligns the y label to the left of y = 0
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    
    // Sets the max and min values of the x and y axis.
    // This changes how the chart is displayed the first time.
    // This should be a bit higher and lower than the highest and lowest
    // values that will be displayed.
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(8);
    /*
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(5.0);
    */
    
    

    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(yAxisMax);
    

    
    //mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    /*
    mRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
    mRenderer.setZoomRate(0.2f); 
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 70, 50, 50, 30 });
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.2f);
    */
    
}
```

Does someone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Uhh thanks. :D
I am desperate here.
I am surprised that no one has the answer to this. :/

Comment: I have used 45 degree slanted labels, and would recommend the same. I have used AFreeChart though and had to hack it into the library.

Comment: But I do not need to do anything with the labels...
It is the values of the bars that need changing.

Comment: You have written that _need to turn the values 45 degrees._ - maybe that's easier :)

Comment: Need to turn the values of the bars 45 degrees. The values of the bars are the double values on top of the bars.
Turning the LABELS 45 degrees is not solving my problem.

Comment: Use a smaller typeface size for these labels.

Comment: Do you mean this line: rendererLastWeek.setChartValuesTextSize(16); ?
If I make it any smaller then it will be hard to read.  :(